# I need to find prototype.js based slide out tab?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have founded this -> http://www.building58.com/examples/tabSlideOut.html

But there are some reasons that i dont want to use it:

1. i need prototype framework instead of jquery
2. i need an image to open slider (click to open) and when it opened image will change to "click to close"

Maybe someone has already the same solution of my question?

thank for you help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS transitions were made for this sort of thing! For a demonstration of what you're looking for see http://jsfiddle.net/Fw7MQ/ (The 'handle' changes background colour but you could easily make that a background image instead)

The crucial parts of CSS are;

```
#drawer {
    position: relative;
    left: -200px;
    /* transition is repeated for all supporting browsers */
    -webkit-transition: left 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: left 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: left 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: left 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: left 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
#drawer.open {
    left: 0;
}
```

The 'drawer' has a class name added or removed as necessary using this tiny javascript snippet;

```
Event.observe('handle', 'click', Element.toggleClassName.curry('drawer', 'open'))
```

...but you could dispense with even that if the animation was done on mouseover instead - change the CSS selector from `#drawer.open` to `#drawer:hover`.

For older browsers it degrades gracefully, the animation doesn't play but the drawer still appears in the right place.

Comment: What about it doesn't work? And is the problem restricted to only one browser?

Comment: Ooops, sorry i didnt notice that this only works in new brawsers. but my users use soem old brawsers and dont want to upgrade them, so i need something better solution :(